# Rename row names from a set of dataframe

Tags: r, string

I would like to rename the rownames for this set of dataframe from:

```
   names                              
   <chr>                               
 1 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___1      
 2 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___2      
 3 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___3 
 4 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1___1
 5 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1___2
...
```

to:

```
   names                              
   <chr>                               
 1 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0      
 2 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0      
 3 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0
 4 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1
 5 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1
...
```

(dropping the 3 underscores and number after it)

What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression in `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
df %>%
  mutate(names = str_remove_all(names, "(_+_+_+\\d)")
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `sub` to 3 underscore and a number.

```
df <- transform(df, names = sub('_{3}\\d+$', '', names))
df
#                           names
#1 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0
#2 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0
#3 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0
#4 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1
#5 Reporter_intensity_corrected_1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___1", 
"Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___2", "Reporter_intensity_corrected_0___3", 
"Reporter_intensity_corrected_1___1", "Reporter_intensity_corrected_1___2"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```